# Post data to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

Hi i have end point to post data to mongodb , when i submit a form only ID is submitted I think because am using insert instead of save ,

Here is how it looks:

```
app.post('/comments', (req, res) => {
        const { errors, isVal } = validate(req.body);
        if (isVal){
            const { author, description } = req.body;
            db.collection('comments').insert({ author, description }, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.status(500).json({ errors: { global: "Oops something is right!" }});
                } else {
                    res.json({ comments: result.ops[0] });
                } 
            })

        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ errors });
        }

    });
```

The method above is the one saves only ID, other data saved null: I tried to change like this, replacing insert with save some one suggested something like this.

```
app.post('/comments', (req, res) => {
        const { errors, isVal } = validate(req.body);
        if (isVal){
            const { author, description } = req.body;
            db.collection('comments').save({ author, description }, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.status(500).json({ errors: { global: "Oops something is right!" }});
                } else {
                    res.json({ comments: result.ops[0] });
                } 
            })

        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ errors });
        }

    });
```

Still the same : here is the result saved in database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b281457f5b629565c09ce26"
    },
    "author": null,
    "description": null
}
```

how can I change my method so that it can use save instead of insert? 
and what is the different between save and insert in mongodb?

Answer (score -1):

Try with this
let newcollection = db.collection('comments');
newcollection.insert({})

Comment: still the same !

Comment: Try to console the auther and  description  after this const { author, description } = req.body;  save function will expect an object.

Comment: `undefined
undefined` result from console.

Comment: console req.body after const { author, description } = req.body;

Comment: statusCode: 200
{}

Comment: result from console.log(req.body)

Comment: That means Post body does not have data. so first add the data in in post body and then try to insert into mongoDB.

Comment: To be fair I dont know how to do that, can you help?

Comment: While calling http post from client side use Syntax: $http.post(url,{ author:'A', description:'something'}, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            });

Comment: but we want data to be entered by user using form input not hard coded :(